# In php, what is the difference between // and # to comment things?

Tags: php

To me, at first glance, seems as if

```
// Comment
```

and

```
# Comment
```

do the same thing. So why are there two ways to comment something in php? Which one should I use?

Comment: One character basically

Comment: There are at least 3 ways, did yo uforget about `/* comment */` You cannot have too many comments :)

Comment: I agree! Python would WISH it had `//`